# Implementing an AtomicByteArray in Java using AtomicIntegerArray

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic-values

I need an AtomicByteArray for a memory-critical application modeled after Java's [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html). My implementation wraps four bytes into an integer and uses the AtomicIntegerArray.

The `get()` implementation is trivial, and the and `set()` implementations is fairly straightforward. The `compareAndSwap()` is trickier. My implementation appears below (it works single-threaded just fine).

I'm trying to identify race condition. One potential scenario is that values changed and swapped back between the calls to `get()` and `compareAndSet()`, but this seems harmless.

Am I missing anything that could go wrong?

```
/**
 * Atomically sets the element at position {@code i} to the given
 * updated value if the current value {@code ==} the expected value.
 *
 * @param i the index
 * @param expect the expected value
 * @param update the new value
 * @return true if successful. False return indicates that
 * the actual value was not equal to the expected value.
 */
public boolean compareAndSet(final int i, final byte expected, final byte val) {
    int idx = i >>> 2;
    int shift = (i & 3) << 3;

    while (true) {
        final int num = this.array.get(idx);
        // Check that the read byte is what we expected
        if ((byte)(num >> shift) != expected) {
            return false;
        }
        // If we complete successfully, all is good
        final int num2 = (num & ~(0xff << shift)) | ((val & 0xff) << shift);
        if ((num == num2) || this.array.compareAndSet(idx, num, num2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I've implemented a basic version of [AtomicByteArray](https://github.com/shilad/wikibrain/blob/master/wikibrain-utils/src/main/java/org/wikibrain/utils/AtomicByteArray.java) that integrates the improvements in the answer below.

Comment: I would `i / 4` -> `i >>> 2` and `8 * (i % 4)` -> `(i & 3) << 3`

Comment: Does this belong on [codereview.se]?

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't know, but am happy to repost there. It's more of a concurrency question than a Java code question.

Comment: Which is why I asked instead of voting to close off-topic.  I'm curious where this type of question belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a mask.  This might be quicker/cleaner.

```
int idx = i >>> 2;
int shift = (i & 3) << 3;
int mask = 0xFF << shift;
int expected2 = (expected & 0xff) << shift;
int val2 = (val & 0xff) << shift;

while (true) {
    final int num = this.array.get(idx);
    // Check that the read byte is what we expected
    if ((num & mask) != expected2) return false;
    // If we complete successfully, all is good
    final int num2 = (num & ~mask) | val2;
    if ((num == num2) || this.array.compareAndSet(idx, num, num2)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You want to do a minimum of work inside the loop so that if there is contention you can try again as quick as possible.

I am not sure the `num == num2` helps more than it hurts.  I suggest you try it without for comparison.

Comment: Thanks! I suggested a few corrections related to signing and byte to int to promotion. To be specific, when you perform bitwise operations on -1 (the 0xff), it is first promoted to the int -1 (0xfffffff).

Comment: I implemented a basic version that integrates your suggestions at https://github.com/shilad/wikibrain/blob/master/wikibrain-utils/src/main/java/org/wikibrain/utils/AtomicByteArray.java